# References.addfromfile on Project Open()

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm trying to add references automatically.

The code works if I run it manually but not on Project_Open()

```
Private Sub Project_Open(ByVal pj As Project)

    Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\PJCALEND.DLL")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason why it wasn't working. When I open the project it also opens another project for the resources. The `ActiveVBProject` is the resources project. I have fixed my issue by using the index of the project I wanted the references in.
`Application.Projects(1).VBProject.References.AddFromFile ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\PJCALEND.DLL")`

Comment: Use the `ThisProject` object instead of presuming that this code is running in the first project.